# What should I use for syncing TFS 2008 Work Items with an external database?

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

What should I use for syncing TFS 2008 Work Items with an external database? I just want basic functionality such as creating and updating work items in TFS so that they match our QA department's bug tracking software.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider to use the Integration platform of TFS: http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you have any experience with that? I looked at it but I couldn't figure out where to start.

Comment: The problem you would have is that "external database" may not have an adapter built for it in the TFS Integration Platform.  You would most likely have to build one.  That may or may not be harder than rolling your own extraction tool.  (Depends on what you want to extract.  If you are just looking for the current version then I would suggest just rolling your own using the TFS API.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in an automated fashion, it is straightforward to do it with the API.  Just modify your work item template to have an external reference for the bug-tracking system's key.  That way you can keep things straight.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I'm surprised how easy it is to work with the API, it is much nicer than the mess that they gave us in SharePoint.